# Java library to burn & print light scribe cd

Tags: java, cd-burning

Do you know if exists a good Java 
library to burn & print light scribe cd, if possible free or yet best open source

Have you already used some of them? It's possible to print either text and images on cd?

Comment: It is unlikely that CD burning software APIs exist for Java. Any that do exist will be wrappers of other software (such as CDRecord). As to light scribe cds - Unless it appears as a standard printer it is unlikely that such an API would exist.

Comment: So you're saying there is no a standard protocol to print a light scribe cd? I eventually have to support single burning programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download LightScribe SDKs for Windows, MacOS and Linux [here](http://www.lightscribe.com/downloadSection/index.aspx), but there are to my knowledge no Java bindings, so you will have to use  JNI to access the SDK functions.